# Any way to limit S3 file upload size using bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm doing browser-based uploads to my S3 bucket and of course, when doing it that way, there's nothing to stop an end-user from uploading any file of any arbitrary size.

Is there a way to modify the bucket policy to prevent abuse of this kind?

This is my current bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Statement1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Statement2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucketVersions",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: I think it is possible to limit file size when [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). The size can be specified as a condition that is then signed. If the file upload is larger than specified, then the uploaded file is never saved into S3.

Comment: By the way, your policy (above) allows anyone in the world to upload and download content to/from your bucket. For example, it could be used to host pirate movies and you would be charged for the bandwidth that is consumed. It is never a good idea to allow `*` to `PutObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have removed everything from my bucket policy and am going to stick with server-side uploads for now. I clearly don't understand browser uploading enough to be doing this so carelessly. Just out of curiosity, what should the policy be to be safer?

Comment: You don't need a bucket policy at all if you are vending pre-signed POST URLs to a web browser client. The pre-signed POST URL contains all that's needed to upload a file to a predetermined S3 bucket/key (assuming that the credentials used to pre-sign the URL actually have permissions to put objects to that bucket).

Comment: I became afraid to continue with browser uploads. It seems there's potential for abuse and I'm afraid to proceed until I understand it better. I already had server-side uploads working and wanted to switch over to browser uploads to save on bandwidth costs but now seeing how little I understand it I think it might be best for me to stick with server side uploads for now. It also saves me from having to deal with users overwriting pre-existing files in the bucket (which I understand can be solved with versioning but it's just another headache). @Marcin

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to modify the bucket policy to prevent abuse of this kind?

No. Instead you have to fully modify your application and allow only **authorized users** to upload content. Your policy with `"Principal": "*",` and `s3:PutObject` is a **bad practice** resulting in your question.

So you have to implement some sort of a login system (can use Amazon Congito), and only then logged in and authorized users can upload the files. But not directly to the bucket. Instead you should use  [S3 presigned urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html).

Similarly, the direct download of files from S3 should be prohibited. Instead [CloudFront with S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/) should be used.

Comment: I think marcin answer is what you need adding to his answer, USE coginato federated identity pools to have temporary credentials, USE cloufront pre-signed URLS or cookies with OAI to secure your bucket

Comment: I don't know how you knew that I was not using CloudFront but I have since installed it and am serving up my files correctly.